# Type error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCom

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem. In eclipse that when I import my Android Project in the Package Explorer I have three following errors.

1:  Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.   styles.xml  /E-Learning/res/values-v14  line 8  Android AAPT Problem

2:  Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. styles.xml  /E-Learning/res/values  line 7  Android AAPT Problem

3:  Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. styles.xml  /E-Learning/res/values-v11  line 7  Android AAPT Problem

Basically by mistake the following project was removed by chance. Before that the project was running correctly but when I import again the errors occurred. Please give me some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your theme in style xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light" />
```